some tailwind class not work on production
I'm encountering an issue with Tailwind CSS classes in my React app. Some classes are not working on my production server, but they work perfectly fine locally. I've deployed the app on an Nginx server.

Verified that there are no differences in the classes between my local environment and the production environment.
Set important=true in the Tailwind CSS config file.
Deleted the React build and regenerated it, but the issue persists.
Noticed that the problem seems to be limited to specific classes; others work fine.


Are you using Purge CSS and is it configured properly to match all contents? What is the config?

Can you share your Tailwind config and PostCSS config? There might be an issue in your content patterns or PostCSS configurations.

/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} /
module.exports = {
important: true,
mode: "jit",
content: ["./src/**/.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"],
theme: {
extend: {
height: {
98: "26rem",
},
maxHeight: {
98: "24rem",
},
},
},
plugins: [require("tailwind-scrollbar-hide"), require("tailwind-scrollbar")],
};
my tailwind.config.js file
